# Why are location services not being used after I allow them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

In my iOS application, I have a table that uses your location to find data that is near you. I just installed it on my iPhone today, and when location services were needed, I got the expected alert that said "MyAppName would like to use your current location" and once I pressed OK, the app basically froze. When I closed the app and reopened it however, it worked perfectly fine. Now that I think about it, this happened on the simulator as well, as I have to run the app a couple times before location services works properly there too. Has this happened to anyone else, and do you know how to fix this? I don't want my users to have to close the app and reopen it for location services to work properly.

Here is some relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error.userInfo);
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");
        UIAlertView    *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Need Your Location"
                                                           message:@"Please go to Settings and turn on Location Services so you can see who's near you."
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        _thisGeoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                           longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    located = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to step through your code in the debugger or add logging to work out where it is getting stuck, but a couple of points - the `didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` method is deprecated, you should use `didUpdateLocations` and it probably isn't a good idea to stop updating location as soon as you get a location as location accuracy can improve over time - the first fix can be quite inaccurate depending on the state of GPS/location services

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because locationManager stops running when it doesn't initially have permission. So you will need to re-run it once you detect that the permission has changed. You can check if the permission changed using the [didChangeAuthorizationStatus delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/cllocationmanagerdelegate_protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:).

So something like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't my experience.  `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is called when the permission is granted, but there is no need to call `startUpdatingLocation` again

Comment: didChangeAuthorizationStatus is being called when the alert is shown, but is not being called when I press "Allow" so I am getting the same result that I was getting before. Any idea why this is happening @Paulw11?

Comment: No.  What version of iOS are you running?  Have you tried deleting your app from the device and re-installing.  I have found the privacy settings can get messed up.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am running iOS 7 and I have tried deleting and reinstalling each time, as the problem is only during the first use. Is there a way to ask for permission for location services prior to viewDidLoad being called? I'm thinking that may solve the issue.

Comment: The permission dialog is displayed when you call `startUpdatingLocation`, so you could call this in your appDelegate